Can't add in DOM corret editable li element
I'm trying to create something like a to-do list. The structure of app is simple - I have one state for storing data of tasks and useEffect which add eventListners on every task. The task could be added by two ways - from base input field and from additional input field (which appear after enter push in task string).
The first part works perfect - all tasks added by base input and show in list and all of them editable by click and added additional input field for adding new task.
In the second part, I have problems:

when I add  task in the end of list  my app works perfectly, but when I add task in the center of list  the final list cut (for example, I have 5 items, added new task after 3-d item and 4-5 items delete) and in the end of list appear new task again
when I add task in random place of list and click on the task before new task, the value of this task disappear

I have no idea how to solve that...
function ChecklistEditor() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const add = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      inputValue.length > 0 &&
      !Array.prototype.find.call(list, (item) => item.taskText === inputValue)
    ) {
      const id = `task${Math.random() * 10000000000000000}`;
      setList((prevList) => [
        ...prevList,
        { id, taskText: inputValue, inProgress: true, done: false, withListner: false },
      ]);
      setInputValue("");
    }
  };

  const setTaskStatus = (id, status) => {
    const changeRecord = list.findIndex(
      (item) => item.id === id.split("-").splice(0, 1).toString(),
    );
    setList((prevList) =>
      prevList.toSpliced(changeRecord, 1, {
        ...prevList[changeRecord],
        done: status,
        inProgress: !status,
      }),
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {}, [list]);

  useEffect(() => {
    list.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.withListner !== true) {
        const index = list.findIndex((it) => it.id === item.id);
        setList((prevList) =>
          prevList.toSpliced(index, 1, { ...prevList[index], withListner: true }),
        );

        const liItem = document.getElementById(item.id);
        const liText = liItem.querySelector(".checkbox__title");
        liText.addEventListener("click", function changeTask(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          const liInput = document.createElement("input");
          liInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
          liInput.value = liText.innerText;

          liText.innerText = "";

          liText.appendChild(liInput);
          liInput.focus();
          liText.removeEventListener("click", changeTask);

          function updateTaskText() {
            if (liText.innerText !== liInput.value) {
              liText.innerText = liInput.value;
              // liInput.value = "";

              const changeRecordIndex = list.findIndex((recordItem) => recordItem.id === item.id);
              if (list[changeRecordIndex].taskText !== liItem.innerText) {
                setList((prevList) =>
                  prevList.toSpliced(changeRecordIndex, 1, {
                    ...prevList[changeRecordIndex],
                    taskText: liText.innerText,
                  }),
                );
              }
            }
            liInput.remove();
            liInput.removeEventListener("blur", updateTaskText);
            liText.addEventListener("click", changeTask);
          }

          liInput.addEventListener("blur", updateTaskText);

          liInput.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
            const liNewInput = document.createElement("input");
            if (event.code === "Enter") {
              event.preventDefault();
              const liNew = document.createElement("li");
              liNew.setAttribute("id", "temp");

              liItem.after(liNew);
              liNew.appendChild(liNewInput);
              liNewInput.focus();

              liInput.removeEventListener("keyup", () => {});

              liNewInput.addEventListener("blur", () => {
                const newTask = {
                  id: "0000",
                  taskText: liNewInput.value,
                  inProgress: true,
                  done: false,
                  withListner: false,
                };

                const newList = [...list];

                newList.splice(index + 1, 0, newTask);

                setList(newList);

                liNew.removeChild(liNewInput);
                const delTempLi = document.getElementById("temp");
                delTempLi.remove();
                liNewInput.value = "";

                liNewInput.removeEventListener("blur", () => {});
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }, [list]);

  // console.log(list);

  return (
    <form className="task-list" onSubmit={(e) => add(e)}>
      <ul className="task-list__list">
        {list.map((item) => (
          <li id={item.id} key={item.id} className="task-list__item">
            <CheckBox
              id={`${item.id}-checkBox`}
              title={item.taskText}
              onChange={setTaskStatus}
              extClassNameInput={item.done ? "task-list__checkbox_done" : ""}
              extClassNameContainer="task-list__task-container"
              extClassNameTitle={`task-list__text ${item.done ? "task-list__text_done" : ""}`}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Input
        isLabel={false}
        textLabel
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        valueCheck={false}
        placeholder="Что хотите добавить в чек-лист?"
        outline={false}
        height
        extClassName="task-list__input"
        containerStyle="task-list__input-container"
        hideErrorField
        button={<IconCheckbox />}
      />
    </form>
  );
}


FWIW all the direct DOM querying, manipulation, and the way you attach event listeners is very anti-pattern in React. All the click/keypress/blur event listeners should be passed as props to the appropriate elements you are rendering, and the DOM manipulations should be incorporated into your component state which is the source of truth what is being rendered. I don't really understand what you are trying to do overall here, but my hunch is that you've a ton of stale Javascript closures and/or lots of extraneous listeners since you never clean any of them up.

Do you have some examples? I have no idea how to do that

Add onClick, onBlur, and onKeyUp props with callbacks to whatever HTML element you are interacting with? ‍♂️ Like I said, it's not very clear what your UX is supposed to be so I don't find it easy to say what specifically to do. Perhaps you can [edit] to include a complete [mcve] and to describe your UI/UX flow, what you want it to do, and what specifically isn't working as expected. In other words, walk us through the UI what a user would do and what you expect to happen at each step.

My first instinct is that you're overriding your state with the splice in setTaskStatus. Can you try to see if this would work for you ?
const setTaskStatus = (id, status) => {
  const changeRecord = list.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
  setList((prevList) =>
    prevList.map((item, index) =>
      index === changeRecord
        ? { ...item, done: status, inProgress: !status }
        : item
    )
  );
};


I try, but nothing changed
